# Find line of distance that ends on a ray

Tags: geometry, vectors

Here's the problem explained in a image:

---

### [image: Explaining the problem]

I have point $P_0$ and $\vec V_A$, I want to find line that ends on $\vec V_A$ and is of length $d$.

Comment: It seems we need some extra condition.

Comment: Presumably you also know the location of $P_3$, right? Also: there will typically be two solutions. And if $d$ is too small, there will be no solutions. If $d$ is just right, there'll be one solution (or, if you like, two solutions that happen to be at the same location).

Comment: Not enough information is given. _P1_ lies on a circle of radius $d$ around _P0_ and you can draw the vector $V_A$ from any point on the circle.

Comment: $V_a$ is not a vector but a ray, my mistake in the image. Ray $V_a$ starts from $P_3$ as indicated in the question. Enough information is given to solve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know $P_3$, we want a point 
$$
P_3 + tv
$$
to have distance $d$ from $P_0$, or, equivalently, to have *squared* distance $d^2$ from $P_0$. You'll "know" the point if you can find the number $t$. Writing that second version out, we seek a $t$ with the property that 
\begin{align}
d^2 
&= \|P_3 + tv - P_0 \|^2 \\
&= (P_3 + tv - P_0) \cdot (P_3 + tv - P_0) \\
&= (P_3-P_0 + tv) \cdot (P_3-P_0 + tv)
\end{align}
Now let's give a name to that repeated term: let
$$
u = P_3 - P_0.
$$
Then we seek a value of $t$ with 
\begin{align}
d^2 
&= (u + tv) \cdot (u + tv)\\
&= u \cdot u + 2 t u \cdot v + t^2 v \cdot v
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
t^2 (v \cdot v) + t (2 u \cdot v) + u \cdot u &= d^2 \\
t^2 (v \cdot v) + t (2 u \cdot v) + (u \cdot u - d^2) = 0.
\end{align}
That's a quadratic equation in the unknown $t$, and its solutions are 
\begin{align}
t 
&= \frac{-2u \cdot v \pm \sqrt{4 (u \cdot v)^2 - 4(v \cdot v)(u \cdot u - d^2)}}{2 v \cdot v}\\
&= \frac{-u \cdot v \pm \sqrt{(u \cdot v)^2 - (v \cdot v)(u \cdot u - d^2)}}{v \cdot v}.
\end{align}

Note that if $$(u \cdot v)^2 < (v \cdot v)(u \cdot u - d^2),$$
then there are no solutions (because the ray is too far from $P_0$). If those two are equal, then there's exactly one solution, providing the point at which the circle of radius $d$ about $P_0$ is tangent to the ray from $P_3$ in direction $v$.

Comment: you might have misunderstood? Length d is from $p_0$ to $p_1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the point $Q$ so that $P_0Q$ is perpendicular to $V_A$ and then use the Pythagorean theorem to find $P_1$.

Comment: your answer was very helpful and ultimately helped solved my real problem